# `update_attribute` updates a different attribute than specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem when using `update_attribute`. I want only the attribute I specify to be updated, but a different one is (one that is changed in a different place that I have no access to).

Here's a simplified version:

```
user = User.find(1)
p user.attributes #=> name: 'something', email: nil
user.name = 'test'
user.update_attribute :email, 'test@test.com'
```

If I look up the object after, I get

```
user2 = User.find(1)
p user2.attributes #=> name: 'test', email: 'test@test.com'
```

So, `update_attribute` is updating a different attribute than the one I asked for.
Why? How can I solve this?

Comment: you're assigning `user.name` to `test` - are you saving it anywhere?

Comment: No, the only save is done using `update_attribute`

Comment: Sorry didn't see - have you answered your own question below?

Comment: Yes, I am asking and replying myself as I did not find this answered anywhere and had to do a search in the codebase to find the answer.

Comment: No problem - don't forget to give it a tick when the timer allows you. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two related methods in Rails for this: `update_attribute` and `update_column`.

[`update_attribute`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77d18edf0dc3aa90438a72ac315de1b739827421/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L213), what it does, is it sets the value of the attribute, and 
then calls for a full save of the object without validation (but calling callbacks). This will cause the other, unrelated fields
that were updated to be saved as well (`name` field in this case)

[`update_column`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77d18edf0dc3aa90438a72ac315de1b739827421/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L267), instead, will directly update that field in the database, ignoring any other changes
to any other fields, and ignoring validations and callbacks.

If what you want is to update the field making sure no others are updated, skipping all possible side effects, the best option is to use `update_column`. If, instead, you want to update a field skipping the validations, I'd say you're better off updating the attribute and calling `save(validate: false)`, so your intentions are explicit.

Comment: Or you can either use `user.set(:email, 'test@test.com')`
But Alex Siri 's answer is all what you need.